# Complex variable string in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, variables, split, substring

So I have hundreds of files in a folder:

The files are always `First_Last (MMM yyyy)`:

```
C:\Test\Bob_Johnson (May 2017).pdf
C:\Test\James_Smith (Apr 2017).pdf
```

They get moved to individual folders based on their filenames (I think I know how to move the files). The folders are named `Last, First 00-0000` where the zeros are the case number.

The following script will remove the  `(MMM yyyy)` from the filenames:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test | ?{ ($_.PsIsContainer)} | %{
    $File = ($_.name.substring(0,$_.basename.length-11))
    Write-Host $File
}
```

Output:

```
Bob_Johnson
James_Smith
```

Great. But it needs to be "Last, First".

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test | ?{!($_.PsIsContainer)} | %{
    $File = ($_.BaseName -split '_')[1] + ", " + ($_.BaseName -split '_')[0]
    Write-Host $File
}
```

Output:

```
Johnson (May 2017), Bob
Smith (Apr 2017), James
```

So here's my question: how do I **combine** the substring and the split so that it trims the last 11 characters **and** rearranges the first and last names with a ", " in between?

**Desired Output:**

```
Johnson, Bob
Smith, James
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the most elegant solution, but I think you could just do this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test | ?{ ($_.PsIsContainer)} | %{
    $File = ($_.name.substring(0,$_.basename.length-11))
    $File = ($File -split '_')[1] + ", " + ($File -split '_')[0]
    Write-Host $File
}
```

Comment: Wow. So simple, yet so elusive. I tried so many variations including one similar to this. But I think instead of the 2nd variable declaration where it splits, I put "$_.BaseName -split" instead of "$File -split". This seems to work perfectly with my code and everything is getting moved to its correct folder. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution using *regex*:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test | ?{!($_.PsIsContainer)} | %{
    $regexMatch = [regex]::Match($_.BaseName, '(\w+)_(\w+)\s+\((\w+)\s+(\d+)')
    $File = '{0}, {1} {2}-{3}' -f $regexMatch.Groups[1].Value, $regexMatch.Groups[2].Value, $regexMatch.Groups[3].Value, $regexMatch.Groups[4].Value
    Write-Host $File
}
```

**Output:**

```
Bob, Johnson May-2017
```